# Is there a Processing 'map()' equivalent for python?

Tags: python-3.x

I need an equivalent of Processing's 'map()' function in order to map a integer that can have a range of 0, 1000 to a range of 255, 0. It doesn't necessarily have to be a universal function, it can be a hard-coded expression suited purely to this range.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such builtin, but you can use the following:

```
def map_range(value, start1, stop1, start2, stop2):
   return (value - start1) / (stop1 - start1) * (stop2 - start2) + start2
```

Comment: After adding this to my code im monstly getting results that arenegative, causing an error as the range was 0, 255.

Comment: I had a typo which was having `stop2` instead of `start2` added at the end.

Comment: This will work, but you need to specify that all the arguments are floats.

`def map_range(value: float, start1: float, stop1: float, start2: float, stop2: float) -> float:`

Comment: In python I definitely need to do no such thing

Answer (score 0):

you can use for to solve such expression with using map function. please cross check my line.
thank you